# on 'touchmove' event see how many pixels were dragged in vertical direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I am binding touchmove events to a div that has a slider graphic in it and need to somehow calculate how many pixels users dragged up and down, so I can adjust slider graphic (really don't want to use any libraries for this, as it is the only place where this functionality happens).

so I'm looking something like this

```
$('div').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // See direction where users drag.
  var pix = //how many pixels draged up or down
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    var touchStart = e.touches[0].clientY;
    var touchDistance = 0;

    function touchMove(e) {
        touchDistance = e.touches[0].clientY - touchStart;
    }
    $(this).on('touchmove', touchMove).one('touchend', function() {
        $(this).off('touchmove', touchMove);
    });
});
```

This will only work for one touch!

It works by getting the initial touch position, and then using that to get the offset when you move your finger.

You'll have to be careful with your event listeners here, otherwise you'll end up with a load of event listeners and a memory leak—so don't forget to unbind the touchmove events when the touch ends.

Let me know if you need any help understanding this!

Comment: I understand what you are doing here, but for some reason am getting error "Cant read property '0' of undefined" for line: var touchStart = e.touches[0].pageY;

Comment: That's strange. Sometimes the touch events aren't initialised, so you have to go into mobile mode. Might be worth sticking a `console.log(e)` in the event listener so you can see what properties you get in the event.

Comment: Really can't figure this one out, set up a js fidle https://jsfiddle.net/3v5e5qza/ accessed it on ipad, but didn't see success alert :/

Comment: jQuery is screwing with your events. `e.originalEvent.touches...`, or just use native events (addEventListener, removeEventListener).